# How to query a single cell value from SQLite Database in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

i Don't know the syntax to query this cell in C# (Marked by yellow color) and return the value in this cell
shown in my Image, table name is `Contacts` and the name of Database is `MyDataBase` the 1st row describes the type of the columns and not part of my table ,thx

[image]

here is the code i used

```
var dbconn = new SQLiteConnection("MyDBpath"); 
var command = dbconn.CreateCommand("Select VR from Contatcs where _id = 4");
command.CommandText = "Select VR from Contacts where _id = 4";
```

idk how to excute that query and assign the value of that query  to a variable so that i can use that value else where

Comment: Can you show your try and explain where you are blocking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.NET Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=visual-studio) package to connect to your "MyDataBase" database.

Then it's just basic SQL syntax you would set for your CommandText. But the syntax would depend on what you are querying. The unique ID is your primary key, so if you have this info you would want to use the following syntax:

```
select VR from Contacts where _id = 4;
```

Comment: i reached this far now what i should do :/ `var dbconn = new SQLiteConnection("MyDBpath");
            var command = dbconn.CreateCommand("Select VR from Contatcs where _id = 4");
            command.CommandText = "Select VR from Contacts where _id = 4";`

Comment: Did you look at the link? It shows how to execute the SQL:  

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var name = reader.GetString(0);

            Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}!");
        }

Comment: `var command = connection.CreateCommand()` it gives an error no overload method that takes 0 arguments beside there is no definition for `open` in `SQLiteConnection` in `connection.Open();` there is somth wrong with the documentation